# How to duplicate an image in document folder in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a image cached in my apps document folder. I want to copy it in document folder. Till now i know that i can load my image as UIImage and then convert it to data and save it in my destination path. But is there any better approach than this? Like i don't want to convert my image in UIImage and again convert it to data and write.

My code for png is:

```
// Here sourcePath is original image path for example file//Document/dummy.png
// destinationPath is the path where i want to save my image for example file//Document/Image/anything.png
     if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: sourcePath), let data = img.pngData() {
        do {
              try data.write(to: destinationPath)
          } catch {
                
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileManager` provides an [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407903-copyitem) to do that

```
try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: sourcePath, toPath: destinationPath)
```

or – preferable – the [URL related counterpart](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412957-copyitem)

```
try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
```

A path is just a simple `String`, with an `URL` you have instant access to a lot of attributes and metadata. Further `URL` provides all APIs to manipulate URLs for example changing the path extension or adding path components, for remote URLs even you can reliably manage components like `scheme`, `host`, `query` and `fragment`.

Comment: I've always used the URL version, as it's the accepted best practice, but never bothered to think why!  Do you happen to know, and can fit it into comment-sized reply ? :-)

Comment: Thank you i know that i can copy files but was not understanding why it was not working for image. Just now i noticed that i gave wrong destination path. Thanks btw.

Comment: thanks @vadian. Kind of obvious if I *had* thought about it!

Comment: @ArnabAhamedSiam just to make it complete if you need to rename a file you can use `moveItem` and choose a different name at the destination url